# How to avoid ternary on complicated boolean expression

Tags: javascript, boolean, ternary-operator

In linting my Javascript, I ran across a `no-unneeded-ternary` warning on a complex ternary option of mine.

I know how to solve this on simple boolean expressions:

```
var obvious = (1 === 1) ? true : false;
// can simply become:
var obvious = (1 === 1);
```

However, on my below boolean expression, I don't know how to properly narrow this down without fear of breaking something which happens to be very complicated:

```
const include =
  (options.directory && file !== '.') ? false :
  (!dotted) ? true :
  (dotted && options.all) ? true :
  (dotted && !implied && options.almostall) ? true :
  (options.directory && file === '.') ? true :
  false;
```

What would be the proper shorthand implementation of this?

---

#### Taking a stab at it:

```
const include = !(options.directory && file !== '.') || 
  (!dotted) || 
  (dotted && options.all) ||
  (dotted && !implied && options.almostall) ||
  (options.directory && file === '.');
```

Is this correct?

Comment: In my opinion - though sometimes it looks really impressive to come up with one-liners for complex conditions, patterns like these are not readable, and the code is not very inheritable. I agree optimization, etc.. but an `if..else`  in a helper function would not hurt in this case to keep things readable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write code using a bunch of chained ternary operators, it becomes more terse and typically less readable.

```
const include =
  (options.directory && file !== '.') ? false :
  (!dotted) ? true :
  (dotted && options.all) ? true :
  (dotted && !implied && options.almostall) ? true :
  (options.directory && file === '.') ? true :
  false;
```

To break this down, I will first expand it using a module pattern:

```
include = (function () {
    //set up some simple names for concepts:
    var directory = options.directory;
    var isDot = file === '.';
    var all = options.all;
    var almost = options.almostall;

    if (directory && !isDot)
        return false;

    if (!dotted)
        return true;

    if (dotted && all)
        return true;

    if (dotted && implied && almost)
        return true;

    if (directory && isDot)
        return true;

    return false;
}());
```

This can be simplified. After checking `!dotted`, `dotted` must be true, and becomes redundant:

> ```
> true && a
> ```
>
> converts to:
>
> ```
> a
> ```

```
include = (function () {
    //set up some simple names for concepts:
    var directory = options.directory;
    var isDot = file === '.';
    var all = options.all;
    var almost = options.almostall;

    if (directory && !isDot)
        return false;

    if (!dotted)
        return true;

    if (all)
        return true;

    if (implied && almost)
        return true;

    if (directory && isDot)
        return true;

    return false;
}());
```

As a matter of leaving well enough alone, you could feel free to stop here knowing that the code is simple and efficient.

---

Of course...this can be simplified. The last `if` statement can be changed to a `return`:

> ```
> if (a)
>     return true;
> return false;
> ```
>
> converts to:
>
> ```
> return a;
> ```

```
include = (function () {
    //set up some simple names for concepts:
    var directory = options.directory;
    var isDot = file === '.';
    var all = options.all;
    var almost = options.almostall;

    if (directory && !isDot)
        return false;

    if (!dotted)
        return true;

    if (all)
        return true;

    if (implied && almost)
        return true;

    return directory && isDot;
}());
```

which of course can be simplified by converting the last `if` to a `return` again:

> ```
> if (a)
>     return true;
> return b;
> ```
>
> converts to:
>
> ```
> return a || b;
> ```

```
include = (function () {
    //set up some simple names for concepts:
    var directory = options.directory;
    var isDot = file === '.';
    var all = options.all;
    var almost = options.almostall;

    if (directory && !isDot)
        return false;

    if (!dotted)
        return true;

    if (all)
        return true;

    return (implied && almost) ||
        (directory && isDot);
}());
```

...and again:

```
include = (function () {
    //set up some simple names for concepts:
    var directory = options.directory;
    var isDot = file === '.';
    var all = options.all;
    var almost = options.almostall;

    if (directory && !isDot)
        return false;

    if (!dotted)
        return true;

    return (all) ||
        (implied && almost) ||
        (directory && isDot);
}());
```

...and again:

```
include = (function () {
    //set up some simple names for concepts:
    var directory = options.directory;
    var isDot = file === '.';
    var all = options.all;
    var almost = options.almostall;

    if (directory && !isDot)
        return false;

    return (!dotted) ||
        (all) ||
        (implied && almost) ||
        (directory && isDot);
}());
```

...and again:

> ```
> if (a)
>     return false;
> return b;
> ```
>
> converts to:
>
> ```
> return !a && b;
> ```

```
include = (function () {
    //set up some simple names for concepts:
    var directory = options.directory;
    var isDot = file === '.';
    var all = options.all;
    var almost = options.almostall;

    return !(directory && !isDot) && (
        (!dotted) ||
        (all) ||
        (implied && almost) ||
        (directory && isDot)
    );
}());
```

This can be simplified further by using [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

> ```
> !(a && b)
> ```
>
> converts to:
>
> ```
> !a || !b
> ```

```
include = (function () {
    //set up some simple names for concepts:
    var directory = options.directory;
    var isDot = file === '.';
    var all = options.all;
    var almost = options.almostall;

    return (!directory || isDot) && (
        (!dotted) ||
        (all) ||
        (implied && almost) ||
        (directory && isDot)
    );
}());
```

---

And there you have it, about as simple as the logic can get. You could, of course, choose to expand the variables back to their original definition, but I would encourage you not to. I would actually encourage you not to simplify beyond the simple chain of `if..return` statements.

If you make the code terser it's more challenging to read and understand which makes it more challenging to debug. It's quite likely that I've made a mistake somewhere in this post while "simplifying" the code, and it's not immediately obvious when reading the series of `&&` and `||` operators if mistakes were made.